# I am unable to open Web.Config in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I had Visual Studio 2010 working perfectly before i installed the VS2012 Express edition. After that I found two major issues

1. I was unable to use drag and drop feature in 2010 dbml file.
2. Whenever I tried to open web to config file, using double click VS2010 freezes.right click will open the file, but as a normal HTML file or XML where i can't have the benefit of the intellisense.

Comment: Does it happen in a new solution as well ?

Comment: @Ofiris yes in any solution or any project irrespective of new or old

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the markup designers, but for the DBMLs, I've had this issue after installing VS or SQL 2012 components on a system with VS2010.

The 2012 installation replaces a couple DLLs that 2010 uses as well in a way that 2010 can no longer use them. whats worse is uninstalling the 2012 product does not restore the original dlls.

see this thread for details on how to fix it:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d65c71f5-3887-4f2a-bbd3-e799a4ac6fdc/visual-studio-database-tools-error